# Error with tikz after upgrading to MacTex 2021

Tags: tikz-pgf, mactex, compilation-error

I installed MacTeX 2021 on my Mac (BigSur). Now my latex code using TikZ does not work anymore; it still  works with MacTex 2019. In a minimal example: just an empty document with `\usepackage{tikz}` in the preamble gives the following error.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2073 \pgfutil@protected
                         \def\tikz@signal@path{\tikz@signal@path}%
```

In texlive it appears that I have the most recent path and spath3 packages. Did something go wrong with the installation? (I tried it twice.) Does it use other paths than the previous version?

My small example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{blabla} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

And here is the .log file https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/YvidDTrw

Comment: Can you please post the exact minimal document that you ran? (Posting the exact document you ran helps avoid confusion. *Technically*, an empty document with just `\usepackage{tikz}` is not a valid LaTeX file...) Please also upload the complete `.log` file of the LaTeX run. If the `.log` file is too long to be included here (it probably is short enough if the example is truly minimal), please upload it to a text-sharing service such as https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're using a nonstandard file

```
/Users/nmegow/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf-bugfix/pgfutil-latex.def
```

instead of the currently distributed `pgfutil-latex.def` file. Possibly you wanted to fix a bug, but that file seems to be the culprit, because your example file doesn't fail for me.

You are also loading `/Users/nmegow/Library/texmf/tex/latex/keyval.sty`: remove this file so TeX will use the standard `keyval.sty`.

Comment: Awesome, that solved my problems! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Remove any packages that aren't personally yours from your personal tree `~/Library/texmf` since they will take precedence over newer versions in TeX Live 2021.